# Create a guestbook application in HTML with some conditions in the input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to create a guestbook application page in HTML which has 3 fields for the user to input:

1. Name
2. E-mail
3. Message

I wanna make the client check in JavaScript, so below are my snippets of code which I added in the head of the html page.

1. For the Name I need to put a condition so only letters can be entered, no numbers, no special characters, no spaces or empty field, so I made this

   ```
   function Validate()
   {
       var x=document.forms["guest"]["email"].value;
       var y=document.forms["guest"]["name"].value;
       var regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

       if( y==null || y=="" || (!y.match(regex)))
       {
           alert("Please enter your Name! ");
           return false;
       }
   ```

**My question is**: How can I insert a condition so the  name must be bigger than 3 letters?

2. For the e-mail field I made this:

   ```
   if(x==null || x=="")
   {
       alert("Please enter your email address!");
       return false;
   }
   var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
   var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

   if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
   {
       alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
       return false;
   }
   else
       return true;
   }
   ```

Here I don`t have any question.

3. For the message field I need to add a condition so the message must be bigger than 10 characters.

Can you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Strings have a `.length` property you can examine.

Comment: Read about HTML5 inputs.  Much of what you're looking for is already built in.

Comment: A bit of unrelated advice. Do yourself a favor and give your variables *meaningful names*. In 4 months when your code is more complex and you dont remember writing this part, you'll hate yourself for naming them stuff like *x* and *y*.

Answer (score 1):

You really dont even need javascript for this:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" name="email" required title="Valid email required" required>
  <br>
  <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}" name="name" required title="Letters only and at least 4 characters" required>
  <br>
  <input type="text" pattern=".{10,}" name="message" required title="10 characters minimum" required>
  <br>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Name should be longer than 3 letters to.

Comment: @Nils You're correct, I missed the 4 letter minimum. That said, your suggested edit to `pattern="[a-zA-Z]+.{3,}"` is wrong as it would negate the letters only requirement. Corrected to `pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}"` which enforces both. Also, note that editing answers is generally frowned on and those edits are very likely to get rejected even if the edit is correct. Your comment advising of the issue was spot on though :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the *length* property.

E.g.:

```
var y=document.forms["guest"]["name"].value;

if(y.length < 3) {
    alert("Not a valid name");
    return false;
}
```

Further informations for the length property on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)

---

An other option is to use the HTML5 *minlength* attribute:

```
<label>Username: <input name=u required minlength=3></label>
```

Further informations for the minlength attribute on [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-maxlength-and-minlength-attributes)

Comment: Thanks a lot.The .length property it's so simple. But i`m a beginner and googled for hours to find how to put a condition on the length of the input field. I solved it also for the message field like this: " if (y==null || x==null || z.length < 5) {
    alert("Message must contain at least 5 characters");
    return false;
}"